# simple_form not applying bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I've setup a simple_form contact page but bootstrap only seems to be getting applied to the h3 and the send message button but not to the forms themselves.

What could be the cause of this?

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Shoot us a message</h3>

  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :html => {:class => 'form-group' } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
    <%= f.input :email, :input_html => { :class => "span6" } %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <div class= "hidden">
      <%= f.input :nickname, :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </div>
    <div>
      </br>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Been using the following resources but thus far with no change in outcome:

http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/articles/7/edit
https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

HTML Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Streetheart</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/masonry/transitions.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrapcss.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/contacts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/profiles.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/masonry/jquery.masonry.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/profiles.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="5cR8ezM88QtJ4ORslrnQQ0/b8p0tihvpVZqCU1/c3cI=" name="csrf-token" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Shoot us a message</h3>

  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/contacts" class="simple_form new_contact" id="new_contact" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="5cR8ezM88QtJ4ORslrnQQ0/b8p0tihvpVZqCU1/c3cI=" /></div>
    <div class="control-group string required contact_name"><label class="string required control-label" for="contact_name"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Name</label><div class="controls"><input class="string required" id="contact_name" name="contact[name]" type="text" /></div></div>
    <div class="control-group email required contact_email"><label class="email required control-label" for="contact_email"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Email</label><div class="controls"><input class="string email required" id="contact_email" name="contact[email]" type="email" /></div></div>
    <div class="control-group text required contact_message"><label class="text required control-label" for="contact_message"><abbr title="required">*</abbr> Message</label><div class="controls"><textarea class="text required" id="contact_message" name="contact[message]">
</textarea></div></div>
    <div class="control-group string optional contact_nickname"><label class="string optional control-label" for="contact_nickname">Nickname</label><div class="controls"><input class="string optional" id="contact_nickname" name="contact[nickname]" type="text" /><p class="help-block">Leave this field blank!</p></div></div>
    </br>
    <input class="btn btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Send message" />
</form></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have a RoR compiler in my head so it might be useful to also provide the rendered HTML output for those of us that don't use RoR.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? simple_form doesn't support it completely yet. You will need to adjust your initializer to handle the new form layouts.

Here's a link with more information:
https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/pull/28

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried directly applying your html to the form elements like so?

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Shoot us a message</h3>

  <%= simple_form_for @contact, :class => 'form-group' do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, :class => "span6" %>
    <%= f.input :email, :class => "span6" %>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    <%= f.input :nickname, :class => "hidden", :hint => 'Leave this field blank!' %>
    </br>
    <%= f.button :submit, 'Send message', :class=> "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The way you had it works for remote form constructs, but you don't need a remote one for this case by the look of it.